# Npm failing to install React on Mac

Tags: macos, react-native, npm

I'm trying to install react native on my mac.
I install home-brew and then node by using homebrew but when I try to install react-native i have this error

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 Forbidden: react-native-cli@latest
```

How can I resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: Yes, but I've already make the command npm config set proxy XXX and when I do : npm get proxy I have my proxy set

Comment: Also try setting your registry over `http` as `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"`

Comment: It doesn't change anything